# Python load library from different platform (Windows, Linux or OS X)

Tags: python, ctypes

I am a Python beginner from C language. Now I have plan to implement a cross platform project with Python + C library (ctypes) running on Windows, Linux and OS X and I have win32.dll, win64.dll, mac_osx.so linux.so files ready.

How to load them by a single Python (.py) file?

My idea is to use Python OS or platform module to check environment, like this (sorry this is not the real Python program):

```
if Windows and X86 then load win32.dll
else if Windows and X64 then load win64.dll
else if OSX then load osx.so
else if Linux then load linux.so
```

Are there any simple and clear way to do this work?

Comment: mac_osx.so? Not .dylib?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the `ctypes.cdll` module to load the DLL/SO/DYLIB and the `platform` module to detect the system you are running on.

a minimal working example would be like this:

```
import platform
from ctypes import *

# get the right filename
if platform.uname()[0] == "Windows":
    name = "win.dll"
elif platform.uname()[0] == "Linux":
    name = "linux.so"
else:
    name = "osx.dylib"
    
# load the library
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(name)
```

please note that you will need an 64 bit python interpreter to load 64 bit libraries and an 32 bit python interpreter to load 32 bit libraries